# TFS service hook bad request

Tags: jenkins, tfs, hook

I'm trying to set up service hook to Jenkins on Build Completed (Succeeded) event. TFS build completes successfully, but service hook fails to trigger Jenkins job.

I get Bad Request 400 error. Response has this message:

> X-Error-Message: Object is null (through reference chain:
>   net.sf.json.JSONObject["team-event"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["resource"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["repository"]->net.sf.json.JSONObject["clean"]->net.sf.json.JSONNull["empty"])

Service Hooks triggered by "Code Checked In" event work fine.

When I "Test" from Service Hook definition screen, it also works.

Only when TFS Build is triggered by check-in, it fails to trigger Jenkins.

Any advice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS (Azure DevOps) Service Hook configuration, change the Integration Type from "DevOps plugin for Jenkins" to "Build-in Jenkins API" and use the "Test" button to try again.

Comment: Do you know what is **DevOps plugin for Jenkins**? Is this a plugin on Azure Pipelines? How can I remove it?